¿Duda que opciones existen para cargar y mostrar de forma segura scripts de terceros en laravel?
Buenas quisiera saber cual es la mejor forma de mostrar scripts en laravel. Suponiendo que se tiene una web desarrollada en laravel se quiere mostrar anuncios, estos generalmente entregan pequeños scripts para mostrar anuncios algunos inclusos proveen de scripts para lanzar ventanas emergentes, notificaciones etc. Entonces mi duda es cual es la mejor forma de guardar y mostrar estos scripts de forma segura. Eh usado mews/purifier
agregando esto que se supone permite scripts
'HTML.Allowed' => 'div,script,b,strong,i,em,u,a[href|title],ul,ol,li,p[style],br,span[style],img[width|height|alt|src]',

Luego en la vista queria mostrarlo asi:
{!! Purifier::clean($adsArray['mi_codigo_de_anuncio']) !!}


Pero al hacerlo esta limpiando totalmente así que en la vista al final no muestra nada. Dado que no logro hacerlo funcionar quisiera saber hay alguna otra opcion optima y segura de hacer esto.

"HTML.Trusted" => true  debiera hacer el truco, pero ten presente que es altamente peligroso habilitarlo si vas a aceptar scripts de terceros

Entonces no hay forma mas segura ?
